# understanding the output of `nvm ls`. Is everything installed properly?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, nvm

I think I may have done something untoward during the install process of `nodejs` and `nvm`.

When I start bash or open a terminal I get:

```
:~$ bash
N/A: version "N/A -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install N/A" to install it before using it.
```

Using `nvm ls` from the command line I get:

[image: result of <code>nvm ls</code>]

going through my history I did find two lines where I'd tried to set an alias (I do believe I got that from a set of instructions I was following)

As far as I know, I'm not having any errors, other than when bash starts up, and those lines are generated from `.bashrc`:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

My primary aim here is to understand the output of `nvm ls` and is there anything there that needs to be fixed.

A bonus aside is, how do I get rid of these errors on logging in (other than simply deleting the last two lines) ;)

I'm on ubuntu 17.04

## Update:

After checking the link in Matt's answer I see that these are the instructions I saw. It appears I missed a little here and there. This is what I have done and the results so far:

#### After checking out the link and runnin the update not much had changed except the `lts/boron` version number. Being yellow, I'm guessing it's not installed anyway. Still not sure why it's in my list then.

[image: after first update]

#### within the instructions I found I missed this one:

```
nvm install iojs-v1.0.3
```

[image: That fixed <code>iojs</code>]

#### So then I tried:

[image: install node, cleared the node->stable line]

So I've cleared the red `node -> stable` and the `iojs -> N/A` lines. They're now a nice green. I realised the first default line was an alias.

#### I set the alias correctly:

[image: things are looking better]

Doing all these extra steps has finally got rid of my login errors, so that's a plus.

#### So I still have the yellow `lts` entries...

I'd still like to know should they be there, have I done something to make them appear, should they be installed? Is there a problem not having them installed?

The funny thing about how it has been setup; I have been running node and electron apps without any issue what so ever! Just adding to my confusion.

Comment: The best way to check if a command has installed run command --version .... If installed you should see a version number print to the command line

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`nvm` is simply showing the default aliases, even though there are not versions installed for all those aliases.

By default, `nvm` doesn't install any Node versions, but it comes with the following aliases:

- `node` and `stable` point to the latest version of Node.js.
- `iojs` points to the latest version of io.js, an old unmaintained fork of Node.js.
- `lts/aragon` points to the latest version of the Node LTS Aragon line (which is Node 4)
- `lts/boron` points to the latest version of the Node LTS Boron line (which is Node 6)
- `lts/*` points to the latest LTS release of Node.js, which is the same as `lts/boron` as of Aug 2017. (This will change when Node 8 moves into LTS)

Since you don't have any Node versions installed, it shows that those aliases don't point to any currently installed Node version, hence the `N/A`.

If you just want to run the latest version of Node.js, just run `nvm install node`.

Don't bother installing `iojs` or older versions of Node.js unless you need them. Just ignore the `N/A` output, `nvm` is just reminding you that these aliases do exist.

Comment: anyway to get ride of those useless aliases?

Comment: I've used `rm -rf $HOME/.nvm/alias/lts` to remove those `lts` aliases.

Comment: @PengheGeng That may work, but there's no real reason to remove them; unused aliases don't do any harm.

Comment: @RyanZim a bit late to the party but they're actually getting in the way when using completions to switch between node versions (`nvm use `+TAB will show all aliases regardless of whether they're installed or not)

Comment: using the code `nvm alias default node` (found in `nvm man`) helped to get rid of the unwanted notification "N/A: version 
"_N/A: version "N/A -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install N/A" to install it before using it._" on terminal startup

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
```

This is the installer script for NVM as documented on GitHub. When I visited npm they directed me to this page with instructions:
[NVM github](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md)

The documentation also mentions that you need to choose the shell and open it again after installation. This maybe with a try.

`nvm ls` should lost the versions of node packages installed

> Listing versions
>
> If you want to see what versions are installed:
>
> nvm ls